# Vertical lines in a multirow and multicolumn table

Tags: tables, longtable, rotating, multirow

I am trying to finish this table scheme but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I want to convert those discontinued lines into continuous lines and I want to center the label "Total" between the 2 first columns.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}[c]{ccc|c|c|c|c|}
\cline{4-7}
& & & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Var Y} \\ 
\cline{4-7}
& & & 
\begin{sideways} Cat Y1 \end{sideways} & 
\begin{sideways} Cat Y2 \end{sideways} & 
\begin{sideways} Cat Y3 \end{sideways} & 
\begin{sideways} Cat Y4 \end{sideways} \\ 
\hline \multirow{6}{*}{\begin{sideways}Var X\end{sideways}} &   
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{\multirow{2}{*}{Cat X1}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{N} & 4 &  &  &  \\
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{}        &                &  
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\%} & 100.00\% &  &  & \\
\cline{2-7} &
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{\multirow{2}{*}{Cat X2}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{N} &  & 7 & 3 &    \\
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{}        &                &  
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\%}&  & 70.00\% & 30.00\% &  \\    \cline{2-7} &
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{\multirow{2}{*}{Cat X3}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{N} &  & 25 &  & 10 \\
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{}        &                &  
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\%}&  & 71.43\% &  & 28.57\% \\
\hline &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{Total}} &
%\multicolumn{1}{|c}{\multirow{2}{*}{\multicolumn{2}{c}{Total} }} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{N} & 4 & 23 & 3 & 10    \\
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{}        &                &  
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\%}& 10.00\% & 57.50\% & 7.50\% & 2.50\% \\
\hline
\end{longtable} 

\end{document}
```

The table output looks like this:
[image]

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are "too localized". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: @MartinSchröder You are right, thank you very much for the tips.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}

\begin{longtable}[c]{|c|cc|c|c|c|c|}
\cline{4-7}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{}& & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Var Y} \\ 
\cline{4-7}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{}& & 
\rotatebox{90}{Cat Y1\ }&
\rotatebox{90}{Cat Y2\ }&
\rotatebox{90}{Cat Y3\ }&
\rotatebox{90}{Cat Y4\ }\\
    \hline \multirow{6}{*}{\begin{sideways}Var X\end{sideways}} &   
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{\multirow{2}{*}{Cat X1}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{N} & 4 &  &  &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}        &                &  
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\%} & 100.00\% &  &  & \\
    \cline{2-7} &
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{\multirow{2}{*}{Cat X2}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{N} &  & 7 & 3 &    \\
   \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}        &                &  
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\%}&  & 70.00\% & 30.00\% &  \\
    \cline{2-7} &
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{\multirow{2}{*}{Cat X3}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{N} &  & 25 &  & 10 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}        &                &  
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\%}&  & 71.43\% &  & 28.57\% \\
    \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c}{\multirow{2}{*}{Total}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{N} & 4 & 23 & 3 & 10    \\
    \multicolumn{2}{|c}{}                 &  
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\%}& 10.00\% & 57.50\% & 7.50\% & 2.50\% \\
   \hline
\end{longtable} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think Emer wanted 

    `\multicolumn{2}{|c}{\multirow{2}{*}{Total}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{N} & 4 & 23 & 3 & 10    \    \multicolumn{2}{|c}{}                 &  
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\%}& 10.00\% & 57.50\% & 7.50\% & 2.50\% \\`

in the last block.

Comment: I would just remove the | in the following code lines in order to avoid the duplicated segments.
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{Cat X1}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{Cat X3}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{Cat X3}} &

Comment: I cannot compile this with pdflatex.

Comment: @Elias this has been corrupted by **a bug on the site**  we have repeatedly asked for the bug to be fixed but no response so far, I wil fix it and ping you in a few minutes see http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7168/double-backslashes-disappear-from-code

Comment: @Elias I have restored the answer to working version.