# Complex longtable with multirow, multicolumn, rotation of text, and a strange header

Tags: longtable, rotating, multirow, multicolumn

I want do a table like the next figures 1 and 2.
The table go expand in many pages.
The header is the same in all of them, and I want put the elements A, B and C in the headers of the tables, because they repeat and I have many tables to do and because it's logical.
The rows D are variable, in quantity and arrange, as you see.

I have made the next code, wrong, as you are seeing (figures 3 and 4):
- wrong height of the rows (must be auto adjust)
- the last column must be with two lines
- and so on...

Please, help me :)

[image: Figure 1]
[image: Figure 2]
[image: Figure 3]
[image: Figure 4]

```
    % XeTeX

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}

\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{portuges}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true,
  citecolor=black,
  filecolor=black,
  linkcolor=black,
  urlcolor=black,
  unicode=false,
  colorlinks=false,
  plainpages=false,
  pdfpagelabels,
  colorlinks=true,
  xetex]{hyperref}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lscape}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}\noindent
\small
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{ 16}{|c|}{PLANO DE ACÇÃO} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{ 7}{|c|}{Elementos do plano de acção} & 
\multicolumn{ 8}{c|}{Temas} & 
\multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Avaliação}}} \\ \cline{1- 15}

\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Diagnóstico}} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Objectivos}} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Metas}} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{minipage}[c][16ex][c]{40ex}\centering Acções Previstas\end{minipage}} & 
\multicolumn{3}{c|}{\begin{minipage}[c][14ex][c]{3cm}Concretização\end{minipage}} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Água}} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Resíduos}} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Energia}} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Espaços Exteriores}} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Agricultura Biológica}} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Mar}} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Biodiversidade}} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Alterações Climáticas}} & 
 \\\cline{ 5- 7}

 & 
 & 
 & 
 & 
\multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{\begin{minipage}[c][14ex][c]{14ex}\centering Recursos\end{minipage}} & 
\multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{\begin{minipage}[c][14ex][c]{14ex}\centering Intervenientes\end{minipage}} & 
\multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{\begin{minipage}[c][14ex][c]{14ex}\centering Calendarização\end{minipage}} & 
 & 
 & 
 & 
 & 
 & 
 & 
 & 
 & 
 \\ \hline

\endfirsthead

\hline
\multicolumn{ 16}{|c|}{PLANO DE ACÇÃO} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{ 7}{|c|}{Elementos do plano de acção} & 
\multicolumn{ 8}{c|}{Temas} & 
\multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Avaliação}}} \\ \cline{ 1- 15}

\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Diagnóstico}} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Objectivos}} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Metas}} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{minipage}[c][16ex][c]{40ex}\centering Acções Previstas\end{minipage}} & 
\multicolumn{3}{c|}{\begin{minipage}[c][14ex][c]{3cm}Concretização\end{minipage}} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Água}} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Resíduos}} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Energia}} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Espaços Exteriores}} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Agricultura Biológica}} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Mar}} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Biodiversidade}} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Alterações Climáticas}} & 
 \\\cline{ 5- 7}

 & 
 & 
 & 
 & 
\multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{\begin{minipage}[c][14ex][c]{14ex}\centering Recursos\end{minipage}} & 
\multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{\begin{minipage}[c][14ex][c]{14ex}\centering Intervenientes\end{minipage}} & 
\multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{\begin{minipage}[c][14ex][c]{14ex}\centering Calendarização\end{minipage}} & 
 & 
 & 
 & 
 & 
 & 
 & 
 & 
 & 
 \\ \cline{ 4-12}

\endhead

\hline
\multicolumn{16}{r}{\emph{Contínua na página seguinte\dots}}
\endfoot
% Nada na última
\hline
\endlastfoot

 & 
 & 
 & 
\begin{minipage}[c][18ex][c]{40ex}Sensibilização dos alunos, em contexto de sala, e numa perspectiva de transdisciplinaridade para a necessidade de reduzir ao máximo o consumo de água no Internato.\end{minipage} & 
\begin{minipage}[c][14ex][c]{14ex}\centering Materiais didáticos diversos\par Ex: DVD “Diz o Alberto”. \end{minipage} & 
\begin{minipage}[c][14ex][c]{14ex}\centering Corpo de Alunos e Professores de todas as disciplinas. \end{minipage} & 
\begin{minipage}[c][14ex][c]{14ex}\centering 1.º, 2.º e 3.º Períodos \end{minipage} & 
 $\times$& 
 & 
 & 
 & 
 & 
 & 
 & 
 & \multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Observação de comportamentos. Registo dos consumos.}}
\\ \cline{ 4-15}

 & 
 & 
 & 
\begin{minipage}[c][10ex][c]{40ex}Medição sectorial do consumo de água no Internato.\end{minipage} & 
\begin{minipage}[c][10ex][c]{14ex}\centering Contadores\end{minipage} & 
\begin{minipage}[c][10ex][c]{14ex}\centering IPE\end{minipage} & 
\begin{minipage}[c][10ex][c]{14ex}\centering 1.º, 2.º e 3.º Períodos\end{minipage} & 
 $\times$& 
 & 
 & 
 & 
 & 
 & 
 & 
 & 
\\ \cline{ 4-15}

 & 
 & 
 & 
\begin{minipage}[c][10ex][c]{40ex}Monitorização diária dos consumos de água.\end{minipage} & 
\begin{minipage}[c][10ex][c]{14ex}\centering Contadores\end{minipage} & 
\begin{minipage}[c][10ex][c]{14ex}\centering Alunos e Militar responsável.\end{minipage} & 
\begin{minipage}[c][10ex][c]{14ex}\centering 1.º, 2.º e 3.º Períodos\end{minipage} & 
 $\times$& 
 & 
 & 
 & 
 & 
 & 
 & 
 & 
\\ \cline{ 4-16}

 & 
 & 
 & 
\begin{minipage}[c][10ex][c]{40ex} Aproveitamento das águas pluviais para rega do canteiro destinado à Agricultura Biológica\end{minipage} & 
\begin{minipage}[c][10ex][c]{14ex}\centering Bidões e mangueiras usadas\end{minipage} & 
\begin{minipage}[c][10ex][c]{14ex}\centering Militares, alunos e professores.\end{minipage} & 
\begin{minipage}[c][10ex][c]{14ex}\centering 1.º, 2.º e 3.º Períodos\end{minipage} & 
 $\times$& 
 & 
 & 
 & 
 & 
 & 
 & 
 & \multirow{0}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Registo fotográfico.}}
\\

\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

doing like David Carlisle in [Vertical lines in a multirow and multicolumn table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88972/vertical-lines-in-a-multirow-and-multicolumn-table) i have this table:

```
% XeLaTeX

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}

\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{portuges}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true,
  citecolor=black,
  filecolor=black,
  linkcolor=black,
  urlcolor=black,
  unicode=false,
  colorlinks=false,
  plainpages=false,
  pdfpagelabels,
  colorlinks=true,
  xetex]{hyperref}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}\noindent
\small
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\toprule
\multicolumn{ 16}{|c|}{PLANO DE ACÇÃO} \\ \midrule
\multicolumn{ 7}{|c|}{Elementos do plano de acção} & 
\multicolumn{ 8}{c|}{Temas} & 
\multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{\multirow{3}{*}{\begin{sideways}\centering Avaliação\end{sideways}}} \\ \cmidrule{1- 15}
%
\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{sideways}Diagnóstico\end{sideways}} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{sideways}Objectivos\end{sideways}} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{sideways}Metas\end{sideways}} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\centering Acções Previstas} & 
\multicolumn{3}{c|}{Concretização} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{sideways}Água\end{sideways}} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{sideways}Resíduos\end{sideways}} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{sideways}Energia\end{sideways}} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{sideways}Espaços Exteriores\end{sideways}} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{sideways}Agricultura Biológica\end{sideways}} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{sideways}Mar\end{sideways}} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{sideways}Biodiversidade\end{sideways}} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{sideways}Alterações Climáticas\end{sideways}} & 
 \\\cmidrule{ 5- 7}

 & 
 & 
 & 
 & 
\multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{\centering Recursos} & 
\multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{\centering Intervenientes} & 
\multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{\centering Calendarização} & 
 & 
 & 
 & 
 & 
 & 
 & 
 & 
 & 
 \\ \midrule

\endfirsthead

\toprule
\multicolumn{ 16}{|c|}{PLANO DE ACÇÃO} \\ \midrule
\multicolumn{ 7}{|c|}{Elementos do plano de acção} & 
\multicolumn{ 8}{c|}{Temas} & 
\multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{\multirow{3}{*}{\begin{sideways}\centering Avaliação\end{sideways}}} \\ \cmidrule{1- 15}
%
\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{sideways}Diagnóstico\end{sideways}} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{sideways}Objectivos\end{sideways}} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{sideways}Metas\end{sideways}} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\centering Acções Previstas} & 
\multicolumn{3}{c|}{Concretização} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{sideways}Água\end{sideways}} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{sideways}Resíduos\end{sideways}} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{sideways}Energia\end{sideways}} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{sideways}Espaços Exteriores\end{sideways}} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{sideways}Agricultura Biológica\end{sideways}} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{sideways}Mar\end{sideways}} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{sideways}Biodiversidade\end{sideways}} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{sideways}Alterações Climáticas\end{sideways}} & 
 \\\cmidrule{ 5- 7}

 & 
 & 
 & 
 & 
\multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{\centering Recursos} & 
\multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{\centering Intervenientes} & 
\multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{\centering Calendarização} & 
 & 
 & 
 & 
 & 
 & 
 & 
 & 
 & 
 \\ \cline{ 4-12}

\endhead

\hline
\multicolumn{16}{r}{\emph{Contínua na página seguinte\dots}}
\endfoot
% Nada na última
\hline
\endlastfoot

 & 
 & 
 & 
\begin{minipage}[c][18ex][c]{40ex}Sensibilização dos alunos, em contexto de sala, e numa perspectiva de transdisciplinaridade para a necessidade de reduzir ao máximo o consumo de água no Internato.\end{minipage} & 
\begin{minipage}[c][14ex][c]{14ex}\centering Materiais didáticos diversos\par Ex: DVD “Diz o Alberto”. \end{minipage} & 
\begin{minipage}[c][14ex][c]{14ex}\centering Corpo de Alunos e Professores de todas as disciplinas. \end{minipage} & 
\begin{minipage}[c][14ex][c]{14ex}\centering 1.º, 2.º e 3.º Períodos \end{minipage} & 
 $\times$& 
 & 
 & 
 & 
 & 
 & 
 & 
 & \multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Observação de comportamentos. Registo dos consumos.}}
\\ \cline{ 4-15}

 & 
 & 
 & 
\begin{minipage}[c][10ex][c]{40ex}Medição sectorial do consumo de água no Internato.\end{minipage} & 
\begin{minipage}[c][10ex][c]{14ex}\centering Contadores\end{minipage} & 
\begin{minipage}[c][10ex][c]{14ex}\centering IPE\end{minipage} & 
\begin{minipage}[c][10ex][c]{14ex}\centering 1.º, 2.º e 3.º Períodos\end{minipage} & 
 $\times$& 
 & 
 & 
 & 
 & 
 & 
 & 
 & 
\\ \cline{ 4-15}

 & 
 & 
 & 
\begin{minipage}[c][10ex][c]{40ex}Monitorização diária dos consumos de água.\end{minipage} & 
\begin{minipage}[c][10ex][c]{14ex}\centering Contadores\end{minipage} & 
\begin{minipage}[c][10ex][c]{14ex}\centering Alunos e Militar responsável.\end{minipage} & 
\begin{minipage}[c][10ex][c]{14ex}\centering 1.º, 2.º e 3.º Períodos\end{minipage} & 
 $\times$& 
 & 
 & 
 & 
 & 
 & 
 & 
 & 
\\ \cline{ 4-16}

 & 
 & 
 & 
\begin{minipage}[c][10ex][c]{40ex} Aproveitamento das águas pluviais para rega do canteiro destinado à Agricultura Biológica\end{minipage} & 
\begin{minipage}[c][10ex][c]{14ex}\centering Bidões e mangueiras usadas\end{minipage} & 
\begin{minipage}[c][10ex][c]{14ex}\centering Militares, alunos e professores.\end{minipage} & 
\begin{minipage}[c][10ex][c]{14ex}\centering 1.º, 2.º e 3.º Períodos\end{minipage} & 
 $\times$& 
 & 
 & 
 $\times$& 
 $\times$& 
 & 
 & 
 & \multirow{0}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Registo fotográfico.}}
\\

\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image: Figura5]

Comment: If the head is meant to be the same on each page, you don't need `\endfirsthead` to distinguish it from `\endhead`. That won't change the output but will simplify thing a little. What happens if you use 1 instead of 0 for `\multirow`?

Comment: cfr, I've followed your sugestions and I found no improvement in the layout of the table. Thank you.

Comment: urelated bu the `\noindent` in `begin{landscape}\noindent` isn't doing anything useful, it doesn't affect indentation of anything it just makes a spurious blank line that looks like vertical space.

Comment: Off-topic: You have both `cololinks=false` and `colorlinks=true` while loading `hyperref`.